# Sorting data in datatool depending on argument

Tags: macros, sorting, datatool

I'm pretty new on latex programming (I used quite a lot for writing text).
I'm trying to insert data on a datatool database and then sort the data according to one of the fields. However, if this field is filled through a macro argument, it works only if the argument itself in *not* the result of another macro. Here the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{datatool}

\newcommand{\sortitem}[3]{%
   \DTLnewrow{list}%
   \DTLnewdbentry{list}{value}{#1}%
   \DTLnewdbentry{list}{label}{#2}%
   \DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{#3}%
}

\newcommand{\aaa}{a}
\newcommand{\fff}{f}
\newcommand{\bbb}{b}
\newcommand{\zzz}{z}
\newcommand{\ccc}{c}

\newenvironment{sortedlist}%
{%
   \DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}%
}%
{%
   \DTLsort*{value}{list}%
   \begin{enumerate}
     \DTLforeach*{list}{\theLabel=label,\theDesc=description, \theValue=value}{%
       \item \theValue~\theLabel
     }%

     \end{enumerate}%
} 
\begin{document}

Sorted:

\begin{sortedlist}
   \sortitem{a}{item}{opt}
   \sortitem{f}{item}{opt}
   \sortitem{b}{item}{opt}
   \sortitem{z}{item}{opt}
   \sortitem{c}{item}{opt}
\end{sortedlist}

Not sorted:

 \begin{sortedlist}
   \sortitem{\aaa}{item}{opt}
   \sortitem{\fff}{item}{opt}
   \sortitem{\bbb}{item}{opt}
   \sortitem{\zzz}{item}{opt}
   \sortitem{\ccc}{item}{opt}
\end{sortedlist}

\end{document}
```

The ouput is:

```
Sorted:

1. a item
2. b item
3. c item
4. f item
5. z item

Not sorted (wrong):

1. a item
2. f item
3. b item
4. z item
5. c item
```

that is, as expected in the first case but not in the second case.
I suspect it is due to the order of macro expansion thus I tried to insert `\expandafter` but with no luck. Can anyone shed some light on the problem to give me a clue on what to investigate?

**EDIT:**
koleygr solution works indeed. However if I introduce a more complex macro like for example:

```
\usepackage[first=1, last=9]{lcg}
\newcommand{\random}{\rand\arabic{rand}}
...
 \begin{sortedlist}
   \sortitem{\random}{item}{opt}
   \sortitem{\random}{item}{opt}
   \sortitem{\random}{item}{opt}
   \sortitem{\random}{item}{opt}
   \sortitem{\random}{item}{opt}
\end{sortedlist}
```

Latex does not compile anymore (TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]). I tried to change the input stack size but it didn't help. On the other hand if I define `\random` as  robust command, the situation goes back to the previous situation (the db is not ordered as expected).
Any other clue?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304278/alphabetically-sort-expanding-newcommand-def-list-elements-and-conditional-for

Comment: I think if you change `\newcommand{\random}{\rand\arabic{rand}}` to `\xdef\random{\rand\arabic{rand}}` it will work... but the behavior depends on what exactly you want to do and if this change is ok for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The change is OK but the solution doesn't work for me, unfortunately. Same error.

Comment: I tested the change and it is not ok for me

Comment: For me neither, I'm sorry my answer was ambiguous. I meant that it was ok for me to switch to `xdef` but the solution do *not* work either.

Comment: @dantard check the edited answer... just doing what you want but without that command. Seems that random numbers doesn't behave very regular and didn't use a command but found a way to give you what you want (hope so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Changed for Edit's request**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{tikz}
 %\def\random#1{\pgfmathparse{random(#1)}\pgfmathresult} %<-This or any 
 % simmilar I tied doesn't work

\newcommand{\sortitem}[3]{%
   \DTLnewrow{list}%
   \dtlexpandnewvalue
   \DTLnewdbentry{list}{value}{#1}%
   \DTLnewdbentry{list}{label}{#2}%
   \DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{#3}%
}

\newcommand{\aaa}{a}
\newcommand{\fff}{f}
\newcommand{\bbb}{b}
\newcommand{\zzz}{z}
\newcommand{\ccc}{c}

\newenvironment{sortedlist}%
{%
   \DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}%
}%
{%
   \DTLsort*{value}{list}%
   \begin{enumerate}

     \DTLforeach*{list}{\theLabel=label,\theDesc=description, \theValue=value}{%
       \item \theValue~\theLabel
     }%

     \end{enumerate}%
} 
\begin{document}

Sorted:

\begin{sortedlist}
   \sortitem{a}{item}{opt}
   \sortitem{f}{item}{opt}
   \sortitem{b}{item}{opt}
   \sortitem{z}{item}{opt}
   \sortitem{c}{item}{opt}
\end{sortedlist}

Not sorted:

\foreach \i in {1,...,5}{
\pgfmathparse{random(9)}
\expandafter\xdef\csname MyItem\i\endcsname{\pgfmathresult}

Item\i=\pgfmathresult\par
}

Sorted:
\begin{sortedlist}
\foreach \i in {1,...,5}{
  \sortitem{\csname MyItem\i\endcsname}{item}{opt} 
}
\end{sortedlist}\vspace*{10pt}

\begin{sortedlist}
\foreach \i in {\aaa,\bbb,\ccc,\zzz,\fff}{
  \sortitem{\i}{item}{opt} 
}
\end{sortedlist}

\end{document}
```

The above code gives the following result:

[image]

You can find this way how to use random numbers with the help of tikz package.
Using the commented `\random` command or any similar did not gave me the wanted result. The numbers was changing every time and inside the Sorting procedure too. But I think you can do your work like above.

**Old Answer**

You have to expand values with `\dtlexpandvalue`:

```
\documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{datatool}

\newcommand{\sortitem}[3]{%
   \DTLnewrow{list}%
   \dtlexpandnewvalue
   \DTLnewdbentry{list}{value}{#1}%
   \DTLnewdbentry{list}{label}{#2}%
   \DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{#3}%
}

\newcommand{\aaa}{a}
\newcommand{\fff}{f}
\newcommand{\bbb}{b}
\newcommand{\zzz}{z}
\newcommand{\ccc}{c}

\newenvironment{sortedlist}%
{%
   \DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}%
}%
{%
   \DTLsort*{value}{list}%
   \begin{enumerate}
     \DTLforeach*{list}{\theLabel=label,\theDesc=description, \theValue=value}{%
       \item \theValue~\theLabel
     }%

     \end{enumerate}%
} 
\begin{document}

Sorted:

\begin{sortedlist}
   \sortitem{a}{item}{opt}
   \sortitem{f}{item}{opt}
   \sortitem{b}{item}{opt}
   \sortitem{z}{item}{opt}
   \sortitem{c}{item}{opt}
\end{sortedlist}

Not sorted:

 \begin{sortedlist}
   \sortitem{\aaa}{item}{opt}
   \sortitem{\fff}{item}{opt}
   \sortitem{\bbb}{item}{opt}
   \sortitem{\zzz}{item}{opt}
   \sortitem{\ccc}{item}{opt}
\end{sortedlist}

\end{document}
```

Found that here: [Datatool \DTLnewdbentry does not take value for key column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375727/datatool-dtlnewdbentry-does-not-take-value-for-key-column/375856) but that answer is for more than one expansions (May be needed for you or someone else with similar problems)

Comment: Thanks for your help! The solution you proposed works but I edited the question to highlight another problem.

Comment: The picture was too long, but items in last list are still sorted